# Web3 Version refuses to update

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, truffle

The official documentation of `web3.js` has this little commented statement saying:

`// in node.js use: const Web3 = require('web3');`

(you can find it here: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/getting-started.html#adding-web3-js)

Well when I put that statement into my code, the `web3` version that gets loaded is `0.19.0`.

And when I take that statement out, the `web3` version that gets loaded is `0.20.3`

Either way, the version that I want - `web3@1.0.0-beta.46` - is *not* getting loaded - and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

• I've already installed the latest version of `Truffle` *and* `Web3` (`web3@1.0.0-beta.46`) a *number of times*, but every time I run my Dapp - on *all* my browsers, they're all telling me they're loading `web3 0.2.x`.

For example, here's a screen-grab of what `Chrome` is showing in the `console` when I run my DApp:

[image]

Here's what my code for this looks like:

```
initWeb3: function () {
    console.log("\n===================");
    console.log("===>in 'initWeb3'!!!");

    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
      // If a web3 instance is already provided by MetaMask:
      console.log("\n\n>FOUND a web3 provider! METAMASK!!!");
      App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
      App.web3Object = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
      console.log("1. web3Object.version = ", App.web3Object.version.api);

      var web3VersionFloated = parseFloat(App.web3Object.version.api);
      console.log("2. web3VersionFloated = ", web3VersionFloated);
      ...
```

The way I'm embedding `web3` is through the `<script>` tags in my `index.html` page:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    ...

    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/web3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/truffle-contract.js"></script>

</head>
```

I also tried this:

```
<script src="https://etherscan.io/jss/web3.min.js"></script>
```

But that didn't seem to make a difference either.

Of course the next step was to go through `Terminal` to see what's going on, and here's what it's saying when I run `truffle version` and `npm ls web3`:

[image]

Next, I looked inside the `node_modules` folder inside of my project's folder, and opened the `package.json` file. Here's what its got:

```
{
  "_from": "web3@^1.0.0-beta.46",
  "_id": "web3@1.0.0-beta.46",
  "_inBundle": false,
  "_integrity": "sha512-a+apA/pXiivrurVEq5Pv9+0GZ5vC6Utu8M9fojW9YUuvory29WFDg+tg+ITBmMvz/dQxInahNS32xJB6HhZbHg==",
  "_location": "/web3",
  "_phantomChildren": {},
  "_requested": {
    "type": "range",
    "registry": true,
    "raw": "web3@^1.0.0-beta.46",
    "name": "web3",
    "escapedName": "web3",
    "rawSpec": "^1.0.0-beta.46",
    "saveSpec": null,
    "fetchSpec": "^1.0.0-beta.46"
  },
  "_requiredBy": [
    "#USER",
    "/"
  ],
  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/web3/-/web3-1.0.0-beta.46.tgz",
  "_shasum": "03b5eb25e4ca1130f4775e43964c19dad2aecdc2",
  "_spec": "web3@^1.0.0-beta.46",
  ...
```

Clearly, it says `web3@^1.0.0-beta.46` everywhere.

I also checked the `package.json` file inside of my project's root folder, and its got this:

```
  ...

  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
    "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "^1.0.4",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.46"
  }
```

In short, everywhere I've looked the indications are for `web3 v. 1.0.xxx` - so why are my browsers telling me they're loading `web3 0.2.xxx`?

Does this all go back to `node.js` somehow?

Or Is there some other file buried somewhere deep that is somehow overriding everything and injecting this older version?

Final note: the official `web3.js` docs say to use `givenProvider`:

`const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "ws://localhost:8546");`

but every single tutorial I've seen says to use `currentProvider`.

So which is it: `givenProvider`, or `currentProvider`?

I'd really appreciate any ideas that could help me solve this.